# combine two dataframes with specific columns being the difference

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to combine `A` and `B` with column `age` and `name` being their abstract difference. If one of the them is `NaN`, set as the abstract of non-NaN value; if both are NaN, set as 0.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

B =pd.DataFrame({'age':[1,2], 'name':[np.nan,5]}, index=['a', 'b'])
A =pd.DataFrame({'age':[1,2,3], 'name':[4,5,np.nan], 'work':[7,8,9]}, index=['a', 'b','c'])
```

with expected result

```
   age  name  work
a  0.0   4     7
b  0.0   0.0   8
c  3     0.0   9
```

I have two questions:

1. So what's the most simply way to obtain above result?

I thought about one way using `np.abs(A - B)`, but the result is

```
   age  name  work
a  0.0   NaN   NaN 
b  0.0   0.0   NaN 
c  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

2. How to enumerate all the `NaN` in a dataframe to fulfill the value if A or B has a value in corresponding cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
A-B.reindex_like(A).fillna(0)
```

Or shorter:

```
A.sub(B, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   age  name  work
a  0.0   4.0   7.0
b  0.0   0.0   8.0
c  3.0   NaN   9.0
```

Comment: thanks, is there any way to solve the second question? enumerate all NaN in a dataframe with obtaining their index and column?